# Filter date by year, please help me find mistakes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i wrote this code to filter date by specific year

```
class Record(db.Model):
    StartDate = db.DateProperty(required=True)
    Description = db.StringProperty()

    @db.ComputedProperty
    def RequestYear(self):
        return self.StartDate.year
```

then i try

`records = Record.all().filter("RequestYear", 2011)` or

`records = Record.all().filter("RequestYear = ", 2011)`

but `records` doesn't has any data from my Datastore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A computed property is actually stored in the datastore. If you've added it since you saved your original data, you won't get any results until you've updated all the existing entities to include the new data - you should be able to just iterate through and re-save them.